# strptime returning NA - even when using on systime as string with the same format code

Tags: r, strptime

I'm completely baffled:

`strptime(format(Sys.time(), "%Y%a%b%e %R%p"),format="%Y%a%b%e %R%p")`

returns `NA`

I was wondering why I always got `NA`s, so I tried to convert `Sys.time` to a string and immediately back to `POSIXct` using the exact identical format code.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the right date format:

```
strptime(format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

returns what you want:

"2018-03-09 10:33:52 CET"

Comment: Indeed...! But the Timestamps I want to convert actually look like this:

"2018TueMar 6 10:00am"

I'd hate to preprocess these. Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with the system locale. My native system locale is German. I used

> Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English")

to set it to English. However, this obviously doesn't go deep enough. I set my Windows system locale to English / United States, and now my original code works. This is awful!

Update: Using

> Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English_United States")

solves the problem.